# Java, Spring MVC, simplest way to pull any type of file (.png, .jpg, .pdf, .doc, etc) from server and give to user for download?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, download

I have been searching on this but the info I am finding seems overly complex for what I am trying to do or involves having to specify exactly what type of file is being downloaded and use a specific Java class for that, I'm wondering if there is a way to not have to do this and to be able to use one way of doing this regardless of the file type as I am not generating the file, just taking it from where it exists in my directory. I have a set of files in a folder locally, say:

```
/media/files/files
```

and in this directory I have a variety of different files, .jpg, .doc. .xls, .png, etc and want the simplest way that I can take a given file path, retrieve it from the directory and send it back to a JSP so that it will enable the user to download the file. The info I am finding always seems to involve de-serializing from a blob, pulling from a remote location, or something like this to where the code is rather lengthy and I figure there must be a fairly simple way to do what I am trying to do given that I have the files locally and they are in regular format (not in a DB, etc)

Any advice is appreciated

EDIT Thanks to Costi I think I am on the right path now but I tried this, below, and am still not able to access the file:

I have put this in my server.xml file in my tomcat /conf:

`<Context path="/files" docBase="/media/files/" />`

and then tried accessing a file at `http://myip:8080/files/test.txt` but it is not working, in my Spring web.xml the only Servlet-mapping I have is:

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/d2/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated

FIXED: Forgot that the server.xml in Eclipse overrides the server.xml in the tomcat server which was the issue as to why it wasn't working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want any logic wrapped around the download, you can simply make the files available as static resources, provided that the authentication/authorisation stuff is handled by the container if needed. For this to work, you simply need to map Spring DispatcherServlet so that it won't handle requests to /media/files/*, one simple way to achieve this would be to have the spring servlet mapped to some extension like /*.html, or have mapped to a subdirectory instead of /*. This way, the container will handle requests to your /media/* stuff and it will simply serve static files.

If you need to interfere with the download somehow (for instance, if you handle auth stuff outside the container or you want to take some action prior to or after every download), then you can have a View returned from your spring controller that simply proxies the requested file to the output stream, after setting the proper headers like Content-Type, length, disposition and so on. I don't know of any such built-in view, but it's pretty easy to create one yourself and perhaps write your own ViewResolver that will return an instance of that view for file names under /media/whatever.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, I wasn't aware that the container could do that, I am still fairly new to Java, I will give it a try

Comment: thanks for the help, I figured out the issue, I forgot that the Eclipse server.xml was overriding the server.xml in the tomcat server, stupid on my part but now its working